# Magento 2: how to use a custom renderer in grid uiComponent for a column?

Tags: magento2, module, grid, magento-2.0, uicomponent

In my current Magento 2 module developpement, I currently have the following code in my `Grid.php` file:

```
$this->addColumn('image', [
    'header' => __('Image'),
    'align' => 'left',
    'index' => 'image',
    'renderer' => 'Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Custom\Grid\Renderer\Image',
    'sortable' => false,
    'filter' => false
]);
```

I have successfully managed to switch to uiComponent and in my `ui_component` file I have the following code:

```
<column name="image">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">90</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

How do I change this code so I can use a custom renderer as I use to do via the `Grid.php` ?